# Pending flag indicator visible even if nothing to address

Tags: feature-request, bug, flags

Since we got the new bar the pending flags indicator for high rep users remains even if the flags have been addressed by the user.  I am thinking if there is no action that can be taken by the user the indicator should disappear from bar.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a few times in the last few days.  Seems like they have a timed script for that instead of some nice AJAX (though I haven't looked at the source to verify that).  They should at least evaluate that icon everytime you take a flag evaluation action.